# How can I uninstall ubuntu web browser?

Tags: webbrowser-app

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and find ubuntu web browser as pre-installed web-browser. I find it useless as Mozilla is far superior than this.

How can I remove it from Ubuntu?

Comment: It also cause the system freeze enforcing me to manually force a reboot...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using the standard package for Ubuntu Web Browser, you can uninstall it by opening a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running:

```
sudo apt purge webbrowser-app
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

Comment: Hi. The question was modified to what the OP was originally trying to ask (clarified in a now deleted comment). They just got midori and the ubuntu browser confused. Previous to my edit the question was closed and on the track to deletion. If we roll it back I will have to reclose it, although none of these actions would make sense because both the original question, the closure, and your answer are all based on the OP's mistake.  If you have more questions feel free to ping me in [chat]. Thanks!